Type-safety issue when trying to insert into a table using Drizzle
I have a schema that looks like this:
export const Organization = pgTable(
    "Organization",
    {
        id: text("id").primaryKey().notNull(),
        name: text("name").notNull(),
        createdAt: timestamp("createdAt", { precision: 3, mode: "string" })
            .defaultNow()
            .notNull(),
        updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt", {
            precision: 3,
            mode: "string",
        }).notNull(),
    },
    (table) => {
        return {
            name_key: uniqueIndex("Organization_name_key").using(
                "btree",
                table.name,
            ),
        };
    },
);

and when I'm trying to run a query against it:
import * as schema from "../src/drizzle/schema";
import { Client } from "pg";

export const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});

export const db = drizzle(client, { schema });

await db.insert(Organization).values({
    id: "68184833-8d03-41d6-95a2-4f23c4f097d6",
    name: "org",
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date(),
});

typescript complains that my data is wrong:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type '{ id: string | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; ...

if I add as any at the end it works, but I'd rather not opt out of type-safety. What am I doing wrong?

According to the Drizzle ORM insert docs, you need to define a shape for the insert data:  type NewOrganization = typeof Organization.$inferInsert;
I reproduced your error on stackblitz and this fixes it. The problem seems to be the types of the dates. They both need to be strings.
I think it's best you use .toISOString() (ref) so the date is stored in the database as UTC but without a timezone.
Here is it in context:
import * as schema from "../src/drizzle/schema";
import { Client } from "pg";

export const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});

export const db = drizzle(client, { schema });

type NewOrganization = typeof Organization.$inferInsert;

const newOrg: NewOrganization = {
  id: '68184833-8d03-41d6-95a2-4f23c4f097d6',
  name: "org",
  createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
}

await db.insert(Organization).values(newOrg);


that does not work the infer insert method have only properties that are notNull for some reason all optional properties are not there at all.

you don't need to specify createdAt or updatedAt when you are already doing that at the database level.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
